# can anyone help with this calculus question please?

Tags: calculus

Use the definition of the derivative to calculate the derivative $f'(x)$ of $f(x):= x^2 + c$
where $c$ is a constant. Using this, and the product rule, differentiate the $g$ given by $g(x):= (x^2+1) (x^2+2)$.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? What are your thoughts/the areas where you are experiencing problems? You have to show that you've actually attempted the problem as this site is not one to do your work for you.

Comment: I have only calculated the first part (which is the derivative) which I think is 2x. is that right?

Comment: Alright, do you know the product rule?

Comment: is it dy/dx = u(dv/dx) + v(du/dx)?

Comment: So using those two facts what would the derivative of $g(x)$ be?

Answer (score 0):

So you have discovered that the derivative of $x^2+c$ is indeed $2x$.

Now use this fact along with the product rule to find the derivative of $g(x)$.

**Product Rule:** If $y=f(x)g(x)$ then $y'=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)$

Let $h(x)=x^2+1$ and $p(x)=x^2+2$ so that $g(x)=h(x)p(x)$

$$\implies g'(x)=h(x)p'(x)+p(x)h'(x)\tag{1}$$

But you know that $f(x)=x^2+c \implies f'(x)=2x$

So $p'(x)=2x$ and $h'(x)=2x$ since they are of the form $x^2+c$.

Substituting what you've calculated into $(1)$:
$$g'(x)= (x^2+1)2x+(x^2+2)2x$$

Comment: is it 4x? or 8x?

Comment: Yes they are $2x$ as well. The derivative of any constant is always $0$. So $h'(x)$ and $p'(x)$ would just be $2x$.

Comment: oh ok. so the final answer is 2x?

Comment: No, now you substitute what you know in the product rule equation and simplify.

Comment: -0.02 to 0.02?. or is it 1? sorry this is the first time i'm doing maths in 6 years lol

Comment: I've edited my post to include the next step. Differentiating $g(x)$ would give you a function not values. All that's left to do is simplifying. Can you take it from there?

Comment: yupp thanks so much